# How to solve modulo when base and modulo is prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Can you please explain how I can solve this:

$$
59^{178}\equiv 1 \pmod{179}?
$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $179$ is prime, this is a particular case of Fermat's little theorem.